# Installing Ubuntu Server on my MacBook without a CD

Tags: bootcamp, unix, dual-boot

Trying to install Ubuntu server on my MacBook however the CD drive is not working. All the guides I have seen so far use the bootcamp process (same as for windows) to achieve this.

I currently have a windows partition on my machine (it was installed with a CD when the drive was ok) which I'm going to remove before I do this. Is it possible to boot using the USB drive from the Mac bootloader using this method? I don't want to remove my Windows partition to find that I NEED a CD to do this.

I would also prefer to have a separate partition as opposed to any sort of VM setup to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The Mac EFI bootloader [necessarily](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4399) supports booting from properly-configured USB drives; I've installed Arch a number of times using the method described on [their wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_Installation_Media). If you're in any doubt, make your USB drive before wiping anything and try to boot off it as you would to install just to make sure it'll work.